# node.js express app - invalid router.post URI

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

**Background information**

I'm working on my first node.js app using express. 
I have bug somewhere because I can't seem to match up the URI I'm specifying with the URI in my post method.

**Code**

```
router.post('/widget/:widgetnum/:rules', function(req, res, next) {

        var widgetnum = req.params.widgetnum;
        var rules = req.params.rules;
        if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'router.post) invoked with : ' + widgetnum)};
        if (debug) { winston.log('info', 'router.post) invoked with : ' + rules)};
        if (!valid_widget(widgetnum)) { 
                console.log('trigger 400');
                res.status(400).send("Invalid widgetnum");
        }
        if (rules==null)  {
                console.log('trigger 400');
                res.status(400).send("Invalid Time Conditions");
        }       
        res.send('hello');

});
```

And the address I'm testing with looks like this:

```
 http://myserver:3000/widget/123123/00:00:00_00:00:00_someothervalue
```

where I was hoping "123123" would be captured as the "widgetnum"
and "00:00:00_00:00:00_someothervalue" as "rule"

I'm sure it's something very basic / simple that I'm missing. 
Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDIT 1**

Here's what I see on the commandline - proving that I am sending POST requests...

```
devserver:/var/www/widgettest# DEBUG=widgettest:* npm start

> widgettest@1.0.0 start /var/www/widgettest
> node ./bin/www

  widgettest:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
POST /widget/11231231234/rules 404 713.167 ms - 1025
POST /widget/11231231234 404 75.216 ms - 1025
```

Comment: it looks like you're making a GET request when your code defines a handler for a POST request. Checkout [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for a simple tool to test POST requests

Comment: I am using postman .. and I am POSTing for sure.  I can see the requests on the cli and it shows POST.  I will add this information to my question but out of curiousity, what made you think I'm doing a GET?

Comment: I figured it out.  I removed ''/widget/' from the path in the code and now it works

Comment: Usually for a post request the data is in the request body, and a get request they will be query parameters. Take a look at the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/14551194/3711733

Comment: @mguida hm. that's a good point about sending in the body. I will have to test that.